# json data is not loading in Ext.tree.panel

Tags: json, extjs

I have defined Ext.tree.Panel and on change of combo value, I am calling

tree.getStore().load();

Here is my treepanel code

```
Ext.define('InboxTreePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    xtype: 'inboxtreepanel',
    height: 250,
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
                fields: [{
                    name: 'id',
                    type: 'string'
                }, {
                    name: 'text',
                    type: 'string'
                }],
                autoLoad: false,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'jsonajax',
                    url: app_global.serviceExtn + 'browseS3.do',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'results'
                    }
                },
                root: {
                    loaded: false
                }
            }),
            columns: [{
                xtype: 'treecolumn',
                dataIndex: 'text',
                flex: 1,
                text: 'Nodes',
                editor: 'textfield'
            }]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

In return I am getting json data but data is not loading in treepanel

```
{"success":true,
"code":null,
"message":null,
"data":[{"id":"root/Date-2015-08-30","text":"Date-2015-08-30","leaf":false},
    {"id":"root/Date-2015-08-31","text":"Date-2015-08-31","leaf":false},
    {"id":"root/Date-2015-09-08","text":"Date-2015-09-08","leaf":false},
    {"id":"root/Date-2015-09-09","text":"Date-2015-09-09","leaf":false}],
"totalCount":0}
```

Can anyone help why data is not loading in treepanel? What is wrong in my code

Comment: `root: 'results'` That doesn't show anywhere in your response.

Comment: Thanks Evan for reply, where i need to do change to fix it